# Clashing Strings and Integers

Tags: string, variables, python-3.x, integer, digit

I'm having some trouble, I've finished this part of the program, and it works as planned, it stores the variables and checks all the validations successfully, but I need it to validate so that only digits can be entered. As soon as you press a alpha key, the program crashes.

I know I need to use selection.isdigit somewhere, I have tried it in a few different places, but when I do put it in what seems like the right place, the program crashes because isdigit only works with strings, and given the numeric validations in the program, the program crashes when they try and work with strings. Could someone help me out?

```
while True:
    if amountwanted > 0:                                                                               
        selection = int(input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): "))                           
        if selection < 1 or selection > 12:                                                             
            print("You must enter a pizza between 1 and 12")                                            
            print("")
        else:
            if selection <= 7:                                                                          
                orderedstandardpizzas.append(selection)
            else:
                orderedgourmetpizzas.append(selection)                                                  
            amountwanted = amountwanted - 1                                                             
    else:                                                                                         
        break
```

Comment: ah bugger. my code doesn't seem to have formatted properly.

Comment: add 4 spaces before any code line

Comment: Formatting help: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Comment: I think input is the wrong function here; use raw_input, as it doesn't eval() the string you enter

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `int()` throws the error, as it will only accept strings that *can* be interpreted as numbers.

You could catch the exception instead of checking each character in the input:

```
try:
    selection = int(input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): "))
except ValueError:
    print "You must enter a number!"
    break
```

The above snippet replaces your old `selection = ...` line, which has been indented 4 more spaces to match the new `try`/`except` block I inserted. The full code ends up like this:

```
while True:
    if amountwanted > 0:
        try:
            selection = int(input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): "))
        except ValueError:
            print "You must enter a number!"
            break
        if selection < 1 or selection > 12:
            print("You must enter a pizza between 1 and 12")
            print("")
        else:
            if selection <= 7:
                orderedstandardpizzas.append(selection)
            else:
                orderedgourmetpizzas.append(selection)
            amountwanted = amountwanted - 1
     else:
        break
```

Comment: The program now does not store anything, gives an error message when an alpha is put in, and skips to the next module/step. Have i laid it out wrong?

Comment: @DanielNitschke: Probably, yes. :-) I only gave you an example here, to replace your `selection = int(input(...))` line. Check you indentation, but most of all, read up on exception handling (try/except) in Python. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
selection = raw_input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): ");
if (selection.isdigit())
    numSelection = int(selection);
    if (numSelection < 1 or numSelection > 12:
        // carry on
    else:
        // else case
else:
    //print error message. Break out of loop here if required.
```

Comment: This is working, but how do I make it give an error message when an incorrect character is entered? it just repeats the question.

Comment: Can anyone expand on wills point? It is the best so far. Error Message upon validation?

Comment: @DanielNitschke I've added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line

```
        selection = int(input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): "))
```

The `input(...)` function returns a string based on the user's input; this is then converted to an integer via `int(...)`. [As others have pointed out, `input` in 3.x is the equivalent of `raw_input` on 2.x.]

So you have essentially two choices.  First, you could treat the non-digit input as an actual *error*, which you could catch, and use `continue` to go back to the start of the loop in case of an error:

```
try:
    selection = int(input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): "))
except ValueError:
    print "Error message"
    continue
```

This is probably the most appropriate and pythonic strategy.

Conversely, you could check that the input is indeed made of digits, though it's a little more complicated than that, as the current version allows whitespace before and after, so you could do something like

```
    string_selection = input("What flavour pizza would you like? (1-12): ")
    if not string_selection.strip().isdigit():
        continue
    selection = int(string_selection)
```

But this is more complicated!

Comment: Isn't raw input for < Python 3.x

Comment: Oops, yep. (I usually use 2.x, and almost never input or raw_input anyway!)